# Como passar array em um gRPC?

Tags: python

Estou testando uns códigos utilizando gRPC com a linguagem Python, e não estou conseguindo manipular array.
O código consiste em passar um vetor por parâmetro, o servidor recebe esse vetor e ordena.

> código .proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Number {
  repeated int32 value = 1;

}
```

> Código ordena.py

```
def organiza(vetor):
vetor.sort()
return vetor
```

> server.py

```
class OrdenaServicer(ordena_pb2_grpc.OrdenaServicer):

def Organiza(self, request, context):
    response = ordena_pb2.Number()
    response.value = int(ordena.organiza(request.value))
    return response


service Ordena {
  rpc Organiza(Number) returns (Number) {}
}
```

> client.py

```
# create a stub (client)
stub = ordena_pb2_grpc.OrdenaStub(channel)

# create a valid request message
vetor = [23,65,8,3,89,34,6,22,12,5,9,54]
number = ordena_pb2.Number(value=vetor)

# make the call
response = stub.Organiza(number)
```

O código em si é bem simples, consiste apenas em uma ordenação básica, porém não estou conseguindo passar o vetor como parâmetro. Sempre que tento aparece um erro:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O serviço `Organiza` espera uma instância da classe Number como retorno. Para instanciar um objeto dessa classe, você precisa passar uma lista de inteiros como argumento, já que é isso que foi especificado no proto. Portanto, abaixo segue o código correto do serviço:

```
def Organiza(self, request, context):
    vetor_ordenado = ordena.organiza(request.value)
    return ordena_pb2.Number(value=vetor_ordenado)
```

Mas o principal motivo de ter surgido a exceção `TypeError` foi porque você tentou converter uma lista em um inteiro:

```
int(ordena.organiza(request.value))
```

Comment: Valeu! Funcionou certinho aqui.